# How to arrange column data associated with dates into calendar grids (ie. 6x7 array blocks)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOWHoVUbbtcV_dqWVKM-4mCqNbBwQ__2TRo0IMVaalw/edit?usp=sharing) with dates and values in Data!E2:E, i want to transpose all the values in the column E to the calendar in Calendar!B5:H10. I need a formula to transpose all the values from column to rows, but every time it gets to the border of the month it jumps a row.

First day of the week is Sunday, everyday i plan to complete Data!E2:E cells with 'Yes' or 'No' and they should show up in the calendar with green or grey cells. So i can keep track of which things i did.

I have been doing this manually but it takes too long, i also tried inserting the function `=TRANSPOSE(Data!E2:E366)` in the calendar and modifying the number of the row, its saves a little time but its tedious.

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4eU6.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeKRj.png)

Comment: Welcome. Had a look at your sheet. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Besides providing an example sheet, you should also define your input parameters and the desired output. For example, will your `Data!A2:A` contain all dates of year 2022? The data to display always in `Data!E2:E`? Is your calendar position intended to be fixed (with the cell for the month name "January" always at B5 and all the 6-by-7 arrays for months always spaced by 1 cell)? etc etc.

Comment: Consult [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as necessary.

Comment: Aside, transpose, in general circumstances, means changing the column and row indices of all cells of a given array. Transposing a column into rows of fixed length doesn't describe your problem at all. Your desired output range are 6-by-7 array blocks with spacings in between. It is truly a different question from the current title.

Comment: (I made a title edit for your reference. You are welcome to use your own as long as it describes the question. Also please edit the text of the question for the necessary clarifications.)

Comment: My first week day is Sunday, my plan is to complete with 'y' (yes) and 'n' (no) the Data!E2:E everyday, and then show it on the Calendar sheet, to keep track of which days of the year i made certain things. I plan to make several calendars for different actions (excercise, sleep, etc..)

Comment: @Manu: You should add your 1st week day to the main text of your question. In my answer, I used Google Sheet's `weekday()` to help define the starting cell of a month. Coincidentally, `weekday()` also  considers Sunday as first week day. If you ever need to adapt your sheet to a different calendar grid, look offset the output of `weekday()` in my answer and it will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B5, put

```
=arrayformula(if((row(B5:H10)-row(B4)-1)*7+column(B5:H10)-column(B4)+1>=weekday(date(2022,month(B4&1),1)),
                  if((row(B5:H10)-row(B4)-1)*7+column(B5:H10)-column(B4)+1-weekday(date(2022,month(B4&1),1))<eomonth(date(2022,month(B4&1),1),0)-date(2022,month(B4&1),1)+1,
                      vlookup(date(2022,month(B4&1),(row(B5:H10)-row(B4)-1)*7+column(B5:H10)-column(B4)+1-weekday(date(2022,month(B4&1),1))+1),Data!$A$2:$E,5,false),
                      ),
                  ))
```

Spread (ie. copy & paste cell outside formula editor) the formula to the cells directly below your month names, e.g. J5, R5.

Remove placeholder formulae in your sheet and reset existing text formatting to visualize the results.

You can adapt the above to a single formula by adding a check on whether the corresponding cell for month name for a given cell is empty. It is also possible to combined the 2 `if()` conditions if you so desire. In addition, I recommend storing the year number of your calendar in a cell and then referring to that cell, instead of hard-coding 2022.

Answer (score 1):

delete everything you got and use this in B5. then copy B5 and paste to J5, R5, Z5, B13, J13, etc.

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(6, 7), 
 {SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(B4&"/2022", ))+WEEKDAY(B4&"/2022", 1), 1, ), 
 {IFERROR(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&WEEKDAY(B4&"/2022", 1)))/0); 
 SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(B4&"/2022", )), 1, B4&"/2022")}}, 2, ), Data!$A:$E, 5, )))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dEciBW_R-uaKNsuAF7D-IwvKJ7TsNBfEUS2H4sK2f8k/edit#gid=1156433832)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67755777/5632629